# windows 7 powershell cannot find dsquery and dsget

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I tried to run

```
dsquery group -samid "Development Environment" | dsget group -members -expand > C:\dev.txt
```

and I had this:

```
The term 'dsquery' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spe
lling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:8
+ dsquery <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dsquery:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I already installed **Windows Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1**. But it is still not working for me.

Please help.

[image: The only one cannot be installed]

The Active Directory Administrative Center failed to be installed.

[image: This is the error message]

Answer (score 7):

After installing, you have to go to Programs And Features (appwiz.cpl ) -> Turn Windows Features On or Off -> And enable the Remote Server Administration tools.

[image]

Comment: I did to this, but it showed me an error when I added AD DS Tools.

Comment: Nope, doesn't help at all. Now I am dumping the earlier stage of system restore and reinstall KB958830.

Comment: I reinstalled again but still no luck. If I selected Active Directory Administrative Center to install, the error message is shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but, after reviewing this article I was able to find the reason why I was having this problem.

It was Rights related.  I received the same error. "DSquery : The term 'DSquery' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program."

So, Right-clickeed, run-as "my domain administrator account", then import-module activedirectory.

It now works.

Hope this helps the next person.